# how do i change larger data () in vue2 into vue3 in migration. How to consider ref amoung them?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

Recently we have started migrating from vue2 to vue3 and components have larger data() objects.
How to consider changing them to refs or toRefs? Any help is appreciated.

I have tried changing into refs but still trying to figure if i should really consider changing to refs or not?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `reactive`  insted of `ref` you have to use `.value`  with ref.